# Mongoose update subdocument if record is Unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb  collection with the below schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      Nickname: String,
      Age: String,
      Playlists: Array
   });
```

I have been updating the Playlist with the below query and it's working but i realize it doesn't check if the record exist on the collection before updating it. Hence, i have duplicates if the query is executed twice. Any idea how i can modify it to prevent the duplicates?

```
User.updateOne({
      _id: req.user._id
    }, {
      $push: {
        Playlists: req.body
      }
    }).then(data => {
      res.redirect("/home")
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, to prevent duplicate in your `Playlists` array, you can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)
instead of `$push`. Something like:

```
User.updateOne({
  _id: req.user._id
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    Playlists: req.body
  }
})
```